Adding flutter_background_geolocation package causes build failure
Adding flutter_background_geolocation package causes build failure
I am trying to incorporate flutter_background_geolocation into my working flutter project.
But when I run
flutter pub add flutter_background_geolocation
flutter run
the project fails to build with
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 8 Pro in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available.
.... 5 http sites listed where it looked....

Also, not sure if it is related but 7 unresolved dependencies suddenly pop up...
Resolving dependencies...
leak_tracker 10.0.0 (10.0.5 available)
leak_tracker_flutter_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.5 available)
leak_tracker_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.1 available)
material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.11.1 available)
meta 1.11.0 (1.14.0 available)
test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
vm_service 13.0.0 (14.2.0 available)
Got dependencies!
7 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
I did not expect a build failure to be caused by a pub add of a published package.  Do I need to buy the flutter_background_geolocation license before the pub add command works?  Or am I missing something else?

Have you configured the project according to the Android configuration document?
Android project configuration

Just completed.  It now fails with                   * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

Project with path ':flutter_background_geolocation' could not be found in root project 'android'.


It now builds properly.   Thanks!
